# Tensorflow: determine correct classification shares by class

Tags: tensorflow

I have a two-class classification problem, and I would like to find out how many examples of each of the two classes have been correctly classified at this step:

`correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)`

E.g., I have a share of 90-to-10 of class1-to-class2 examples, and I would like to get something like `correct_class1` and `correct_class2`

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially computing a histogram.

Here is a rough idea. Say we have 3 classes, with

labels = [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1]

correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1) = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]

Step 1:
count for each class (compute histogram of labels): [4 (class one), 2 (class two), 2 (class three)]

Step 2:
correct prediction, element-wise product of labels and correct: [1, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 1] = tf.mul(labels, correct)

Step 3:
correct count for each class (compute histogram of the result of step 2): [3 (class zero: wrong predict), 3 (class 1), 0 (class two), 2 (class three)]

Step 4 (from the result of step 1 and 3):
Result: [3/4, 0/2, 2/2] = [0.75, 0, 1]

numpy.histogram or tf.histogram_summary might be handy to implement this.

Comment: Hi Yao, thanks for the reply. I think the question of how to get the correct prediction count per class from the `tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, labels, 1)` operation remains open.

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer. Step 3 "get the correct prediction count per class". It is a histogram computation.

Comment: Hi Yao, thank you for the follow up. Could you please point me to what method in TensorFlow returns an element-wise correct prediction by class when I feed it a test set with a mix of classes.

Comment: For step 2 you can use tf.mul(labels, correct), https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul

I also updated the post.